# Necessary and sufficient conditions for equivalence between the outputs of two operators

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I would like your help to find some necessary and sufficient conditions for equivalence between the outputs of two operators. Could you help me with the tags? I don't know which branch of math my question belongs to (if to any).

---

Consider the ordered quadruplet $(a,b,c,d)\in \mathbb{R}^ 4$ and define two  ordered 9-tuplets
$$
f(a,b,c,d)\equiv (-a, -b, a, b, -c, -d, c, d, 0)
$$
$$
g(a,b,c,d)\equiv (b-a, -b, a-b, b, d-c, -d, c-d, d,0)
$$

---

Define the operator $\pi_f(a,b,c,d)$ giving

1) the position in the original 9-tuple of the elements of $f(a,b,c,d)$ when ordered from smallest to largest

2) the relational operator ($<,=$) between the elements of $f(a,b,c,d)$ when ordered from smallest to largest

Define the operator $\pi_g(a,b,c,d)$ giving

1) the position in the original 9-tuple of the elements of $g(a,b,c,d)$ when ordered from smallest to largest

2) the relational operator ($<,=$) between the elements of $g(a,b,c,d)$ when ordered from smallest to largest

---

**For example**, take $(a,b,c,d)\equiv(-2, 3, -9, -7)$ so that
$$
f(-2, 3, -9, -7)=(2, -3, -2, 3, 9, 7, -9, -7, 0)
$$
$$
g(-2, 3, -9, -7)=(5, -3, -5, 3,2, 7, -2, -7, 0)
$$
When we order from smallest to largest  $f(-2, 3, -9, -7)$ we get 
$$
(-9, -7, -3, -2, 0, 2, 3, 7, 9)
$$
When we order from smallest to largest  $g(-2, 3, -9, -7)$ we get 
$$
(-7, -5, -3, -2, 0, 2, 3, 5, 7)
$$
Hence, 
$$
\pi_f(-2, 3, -9, -7)= \Big \{(7, 8, 2, 3, 9, 1, 4, 6, 5), (<, <, <, <, <, <, <, <) \Big\}
$$
and 
$$
\pi_g(-2, 3, -9, -7)= \Big \{(8, 3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 4, 1, 6), (<, <, <, <, <, <, <, <) \Big\}
$$

When two elements of $f$ (or $g$) are equal we assume some convention, e.g., we put first the element with the smaller position in $f$ (or $g$).

---

**Question:**

Take two quadruplets $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a',b',c',d')$.

Is it possible to find **necessary and sufficient** conditions on $(a,b,c,d),(a',b',c',d')$ such that $$
\begin{cases}
\pi_f(a,b,c,d)=\pi_f(a',b',c',d')\\
\pi_g(a,b,c,d)=\pi_g(a',b',c',d')
\end{cases}$$ In other words, are the some relations between $(a,b,c,d)$ and $(a',b',c',d')$ that imply and are implied by   $\pi_f(a,b,c,d)=\pi_f(a',b',c',d')$ and $\pi_g(a,b,c,d)=\pi_g(a',b',c',d')$?

---

**Following a suggestion below:** It is also OK if you help me with necessary and sufficient conditions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ (e.g., just considering $(a,b)$ and deleting $(c,d)$). In addition to that, we can start with restricting the attention to $(a,b), (a',b')$ such that $a\neq b\neq 0$ and $a'\neq b'\neq 0$, so that the second outputs of $\pi_g, \pi_f$ do not matter.

As I'm not a mathematician, I really look forward to get some help to formalise these things.

Comment: I suggest you start with a similar question in $\Bbb{R}^2$ and see what insight that provides. My guess is that the equivalence relations given by $\pi_f$ and $\pi_g$ on points $(a, b)$ will have a nice geometric interpretation, and sketching that may help.